# go chart dynamic data

Tags: json, dictionary, go, go-chart

Using this library "https://github.com/wcharczuk/go-chart" 
I want to generate pie chart using json data.

**Code**

```
pie := chart.PieChart{
        Width:  512,
        Height: 512,
        Values: []chart.Value{
            {Value: 5, Label: "Blue"},
            {Value: 5, Label: "Green"},
            {Value: 4, Label: "Gray"},      
        },
    }
```

My **Json**

```
"reaction_summary": {
"ANGRY": 7,
"HAHA": 40,
"LIKE": 161,
"LOVE": 56,
"SAD": 26,
"SHOCK": 6
}
```

What I really want to achieve is this

data = Parse/map json as the content of chart.Value

```
pie := chart.PieChart{
        Width:  512,
        Height: 512,
        Values: []chart.Value{
            data    
        },
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```golang
raw := `{"reaction_summary": {"ANGRY": 7,"HAHA": 40,"LIKE": 161,"LOVE": 56,"SAD": 26,"SHOCK": 6}}`

// Parse JSON
data := struct {
    ReactionSummary map[string]int `json:"reaction_summary"`
}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw), &data); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Populate a slice of chart values
var values []chart.Value
for l, v := range data.ReactionSummary {
    values = append(values, chart.Value{Label: l, Value: float64(v)})
}
// Initialize the chart
pie := chart.PieChart{
    Width:  512,
    Height: 512,
    Values: values,
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: thankyou for your response. It really helped me alot. What if I want to add custom colors to the graph slices?

Comment: @zaheerabbas You are welcome. If it answered your **original** question, mark the answer as accepted. Post a different question about custom colors since it has nothing to do with your original question.